# The retrieval of products from database via search form in Java Server Pages

Tags: jsp, database-connection

I have one question to ask regarding the JSP. I am using following coding to display the products based on the keyword entered in the search form. But i am not getting any result at the moment. Can you please check any error in the coding for me.
Thank you!

http://pastebin.com/BHzRmC6K

Codes:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
   <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
   <jsp:useBean id="dbBean" scope="page" class="source.DbBean"/>  
   <%
     String keyword = request.getParameter("valueEntered");
     if (valueEntered!=null) {
   %>

   <TABLE>
   <TR>  
       <TR>
          <TD><B>Product Id</B></TD>
          <TD><B>Name</B></TD>  
          <TD><B>Description</B></TD>
          <TD><B>Price</B></TD>
       </TR>
<%
    ArrayList products = dbBean.getSearchResults(valueEntered);
    Iterator iterator = products.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Product product = (Product) iterator.next();
%>
    <TR>
        <TD><%=product.ProductId%></TD>
      <TD><%=product.Name%></TD>
      <TD><%=product.Description%></TD>
      <TD><%=product.Price%></TD>
      </TR>
      <%
    }
    %>


</TR>
</TABLE>
    <%
  }

%>
```

Comment: My code is in the the link above.

Comment: I know that. Paste it here. Your question could help someone else in the future, when the pastebin snippet has disappeared for a long time. To make the question still understandable in 4 years, it should contain the code.

Comment: Okay i got what you mean!

Comment: Use a debugger or traces inside the code to see what `getSearchResults()` returns. But it seems it returns an empty list. Note that you should learn about the MVC pattern, the Java naming conventions, the JSTL and the EL, and the generic collections.

Comment: Can you please check this sql code for me: "SELECT productID,productCode,name,Description,ThumbImage,quantity,price FROM products" + 
          " WHERE name LIKE '% keyword%'" + 
          " OR Description LIKE '% keyword %'";